# Draw only outer border for TableLayoutPanel Cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using the TableLayoutPanel for example if I have 3 rows and 5 columns. I want to draw only the outer border for the entire panel. By default the the panel provides CellBorderStyle which adds all side borders to all the cells available. Is there any way where we can set only outside borders?

I have provided a sample code below.

```
    TableLayoutPanel tblPanel = new TableLayoutPanel;
    tblPanel.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
    Label lblName;
    TextBox txtName;
    Button btnAdd;
    int colCnt = 0;
    for(int rw =0; rw < 3; rw++)
    {
            lblName = new Label();
            lblName.Name = "mylabel" + rw.ToString();
            tblPanel.Controls.Add(lblName, colCnt, rw);
            colCnt++;

            txtName = new TextBox();
            txtName.Name = "mytext" + rw.ToString();
            tblPanel.Controls.Add(txtName, colCnt, rw);
            colCnt++;

            btnAdd = new Button();
            btnAdd.Name = "mybutton" + rw.ToString();
            tblPanel.Controls.Add(btnAdd, colCnt, rw);

            colCnt = 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are unlikely to get good answers if you don't provide some more context.  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 9):

You'd be better off painting the cell border yourself. Something along the following lines, then customize:

```cs
public TableForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.tableLayoutPanel.CellPaint += tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint;
}

private void tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e) {
    var topLeft = e.CellBounds.Location;
    var topRight = new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, topLeft, topRight);
}
```

At design-time:
[image: At design-time]

At runtime:
[image: At runtime]

Comment: There is no such code of conduct. This is a Q&A site. It is intended to be a knowledge base of information that can help others avoid wasting time. Please point me to the FAQ where it mentions your so-called code of conduct.

Comment: don't take it wrong. `<off-topic>`now, going a bit off-topic, anyone can ask questions, even out of laziness and poorly crafted... just don't expect to get too much respect... much less an answer (which he got.) code enthusiasm is the only thing that is respectable here.`</off-topic>`

Comment: I went and checked out the edit history of the question. Now I see why you weren't thrilled with the original question. :-)

Comment: Can you tell how this row looks in VB .net? `this.tableLayoutPanel.CellPaint += tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint;` Many thanks!

Comment: @monami outside of the C syntax; the code accessors are the same.  `this.tableLayoutPanel.CellPaint += tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint;` translates to `AddHandler this.tableLayoutPanel.CellPaint, AddressOf tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint`

Answer (score 9):

TableLayoutPanel does in fact support the BorderStyle property, which is what you want. For example:

```
tableLayoutPanel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.borderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

It is decorated with:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

So Intellisense won't show it to you, but it is documented and it works. I have no insight into why it is non-browsable.

Comment: Thank you for this information. That's an unlikely simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve by changing the property CellBorderStyle to Single or desired selection.

Property Change :

[image]

Sample :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

TableLayOutPanel itself does not support a property for border except CellBorderStyle which is not what you want.

I suggest you to put your TableLayOutPanel into a Panel control and set Dock property of your TableLayOutPanel to Fill.

Then Set BorderStyle of Panel to what you want (FixedSingle or Fixed3D)

Answer (score 0):

```
public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tableLayoutPanel.Paint += tableLayoutPanel_Paint;
    }

private void tableLayoutPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){

       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), e.ClipRectangle);

    }
```