# How to set only the border of rows in TableLayoutPanel C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have table layout which i want to set border for rows only.

```
    void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
    }
```

Anyone knows how to do it in winforms, please ?

Comment: Yes,  with the technology WinForms.

Comment: does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239179/draw-borders-around-some-cells-in-a-tablelayoutpanel) help you? or may be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567155/5174469)

Comment: ok which link did you use? I will mark this post then as duplicate?

Comment: ok I took just both links ;)